# AVCaptureOutput takes dark picture even with flash on

Tags: ios, ios4, avfoundation

I have come up with an implementation of AVFoundation and ImageIO to take care of the photo taking in my application. I have an issue with it, however. The images I take are always dark, even if the flash goes off. Here's the code I use:

```
        [[self currentCaptureOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:[[self currentCaptureOutput].connections lastObject]
                                        completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

                                            [[[blockSelf currentPreviewLayer] session] stopRunning];
                                            if (!error) {
                                                NSData *data            = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
                                                CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef) data, NULL);

                                                if (source) {

                                                    UIImage *image = [blockSelf imageWithSource:source];
                                                    [blockSelf updateWithCapturedImage:image];
                                                    CFRelease(source);

                                                }

                                            }

                                        }];
```

Is there anything there that could cause the image taken to not include the flash?

Answer (score 15):

I found I sometimes got dark images if the AVCaptureSession was set up immediately before this call. Perhaps it takes a while for the auto-exposure & white balance settings to adjust themselves.

The solution was to set up the AVCaptureSession, then wait until the AVCaptureDevice's `adjustingExposure` and `adjustingWhiteBalance` properties are both `NO` (observe these with KVO)  before calling `-[AVCaptureStillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection: completionHandler:]`.

Comment: How do you do that? If I observe both adjustingExposure and adjustingWhiteBalance - when exactly should I call captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection? Straight from observeValueForKeyPath?

Comment: Did you find how to do that? Because I'm having the exact same issue right now on my iPhone 6.