# SwiftUI AVCapturePhotoOutput Does Not Work

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, avfoundation, avcapturephotooutput

I have a simple SwiftUI app with SwiftUI life cycle and I am trying to use
AVFoundation to automatically take a photo. I will do this based on conditions or
based on a timer - but for this example, I'd just like to take a photo on startup
and display it (NOT a preview layer). I do not want any user action to be required.

I clearly don't understand the proper setup and capture.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct ContentView: View {

    let dataStore = DataStore.shared

    @State private var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    @State private var backCamera : AVCaptureDevice?
    @State private var frontCamera : AVCaptureDevice?

    @State private var currentCamera : AVCaptureDevice?
    @State private var photoOutput : AVCapturePhotoOutput?

    @State private var capturedImage: UIImage?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Take a Photo Automatically")
                .padding()

            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
                    .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
                    .frame(width: 320, height: 240, alignment: .center)

                Image(uiImage: dataStore.capturedImage)
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear {
        
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
                self.setupCaptureSession()
                self.setupDevices()
                self.setupInputOutput()
                self.startRunningCaptureSession()
            } else {
                print("No Camera is Available")
            }
        }
    }

    func setupCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
    }//setupCaptureSession

    func setupDevices() {
    
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .unspecified)
    
        let devices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices
        for device in devices {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
                backCamera = device
            } else if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
                frontCamera = device
            }//if else
        }//for in
    
        currentCamera = frontCamera
    
    }//setupDevices

    func setupInputOutput() {
    
        do {
            //you only get here if there is a camera ( ! ok )
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera!)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: {(success, error) in
            })
            captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput!)
            captureSession.commitConfiguration()

        } catch {
            print("Error creating AVCaptureDeviceInput:", error)
        }
    
    }//setupInputOutput

    func startRunningCaptureSession() {
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    
        captureSession.startRunning()
        photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: PhotoDelegate())
    
    }//startRunningCaptureSession

}//struct

class PhotoDelegate: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

    let dataStore = DataStore.shared

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

        guard let data = photo.fileDataRepresentation(),
              let image =  UIImage(data: data)  else {
                return
        }

        dataStore.capturedImage = image
    }
}//photo delegate

class DataStore {
    static let shared = DataStore()
    private init() {}

    @Published var capturedImage: UIImage = UIImage()
}//dataStore
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 12.5.1 iOS 14.5

Second attempt to add example:

[image]

Later edit. After correcting my approach with the changes provided by Philip Dukhov,
I still had a problem - the images were still very dark - to the point that objects were
unrecognizable. After a lot of trial and error, it seems that the camera needs some
very small amount of time to setup before the capture. While it does not seem like a
good plan for programming, I setup a slight delay before the session capture. As
little as 0.1 seconds seems to be enough. Starting the capture is now:

```
func startRunningCaptureSession() {
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    captureSession.startRunning()

    //don't know why this is needed - but it works. Low number of tests at 0.1 all work
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
        self.photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
    }
            
}//start Running Capture Session
```

If you know a better way to do this - please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that you create a `PhotoDelegate` but do not store it. In iOS, the `delegate` object is usually stored as a weak reference to prevent a circular reference / retain cycle.

You can fix this by simply creating another property in your view, but instead I suggest you create a model class. If you're doing something unrelated to the view itself, that's a sign that you're better off moving it to some other place, like `ObservableObject`. You can also make it your delegate, so you don't have to create a separate object and use a singleton: that's another sign that you're doing something wrong.

```
class CaptureModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
    var currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    @Published
    var capturedImage: UIImage?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevices()
        setupInputOutput()
    }

    func setupCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
    }//setupCaptureSession

    func setupDevices() {

        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .unspecified)

        let devices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices
        for device in devices {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
                backCamera = device
            } else if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
                frontCamera = device
            }//if else
        }//for in

        currentCamera = frontCamera

    }//setupDevices

    func setupInputOutput() {

        do {
            //you only get here if there is a camera ( ! ok )
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera!)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: {(success, error) in
            })
            captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput!)
            captureSession.commitConfiguration()

        } catch {
            print("Error creating AVCaptureDeviceInput:", error)
        }

    }//setupInputOutput

    func startRunningCaptureSession() {
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()

        captureSession.startRunning()
        photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
    }//startRunningCaptureSession

    func stopRunningCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.stopRunning()
    }//startRunningCaptureSession
}

extension CaptureModel: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        guard let data = photo.fileDataRepresentation(),
              let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
            return
        }
        capturedImage = image
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject
    var model = CaptureModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Take a Photo Automatically")
                .padding()

            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
                    .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
                    .frame(width: 320, height: 240, alignment: .center)

                model.capturedImage.map { capturedImage in
                    Image(uiImage: capturedImage)
                }
            }

            Spacer()
        }
            .onAppear {
                if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
                    model.startRunningCaptureSession()
                } else {
                    print("No Camera is Available")
                }
            }
            .onDisappear {
                model.stopRunningCaptureSession()
            }
    }
}//struct
```

Comment: Fantastic. Understood. I do still have some strange behavior - the screen remains (mostly) black. I can see a faint image underneath and can see the file size so I know the photo exists, but I have not yet found the cause of that black screen. It remains black even when transitioning to another view.

Comment: @JohnSF Are you sure your camera isn't covered by something, and lying on your desk when the app starts up? Try resizing the image to something small, by default it stretches to the full screen.

Comment: The camera is definitely not covered. I did resize the displayed image and that exposes the rest of the view as you suggested but the image is still really dark. I edited the original question to add a screenshot showing the result. Perhaps there is a capture setting that needs to be added. And the camera works as expected when just taking a picture.

Comment: Interestingly, if I move the call to model.startRunningCapureSession() to before the ContentView VStack instead of .onAppear, the photo looks as expected but then it is continuously updating. I'll need to think about that.

Comment: @JohnSF git it, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10863889/3585796)

Comment: Well, that would certainly explain the issue if balance and exposure settings were "slow" to set. I'll play with it, but it would be a lot of work to setup Key/Value observers  and a callback for those. Thanks.